# How to upgrade to rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded via command

```
gem install rails
```

and it shows 1 gem **rails 3.2.11 is installed successfully**. But when I type `rails -v`, the version is still 3.2.9.

Could anyone show me how to upgrade rails ? Thanks

Comment: Since it says rails 3.2.11 installed successfully, im guessing you now have two versions of rails on your system. The `rails` command might be pointing to a specific executable. You should try `which rails` to isolate that and then point it to the right one!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Upgrade from 3.2.3 to 3.2.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253640/rails-upgrade-from-3-2-3-to-3-2-11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from installing the gem into your system you will also have to include it in your Gemfile in the following manner:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
```

Then run the command

```
bundle update rails
```

From the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using bundler. if you do that, you can do a `bundle update rails` and then try again.