# Rails Upgrade from 3.2.3 to 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm upgrading my app Rails app from 3.2.3 to 3.2.11 to account for the security flaws recently found.

I've updated my Gem file with:
`gem 'rails', '3.2.11'`
and ran `bundle update rails`

Is there anything else I need to do to complete the upgrade? How do I know if I need to upgrade any of my other gems as well?

Comment: If things break, try lock Rack to '1.4.1' for now in the Gemfile.

Comment: Lograge gem has to be the newest (0.1.2)

Comment: I found this page useful whilst upgrading: http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also upgraded from `3.2.3` to `3.2.11` yesterday.

Indeed you need to `gem 'rails', '3.2.11'`, run `bundle update rails`.

This will update your `Gemfile.lock` with all the new rails 3.2.11 dependencies, i.e, actionmailer, actionpack, activemodel, activerecord, activesupport, and others.

You should then run your specs/tests, and you're ready to go.

We didn't have any particular issues with other gems requiring a lower rails version.

Comment: Just an addendum: Gems contain a file with a .gemspec extension. This file lists the dependent gems and their version numbers. Updating a gem using bundler will fail unless all of the gem's dependencies can be found and updated to the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed one of the solutions to run `bundle update rails`, but in this case you'll have both versions of gems installed - 3.2.3 and 3.2.11 (you may check it by running `gem list`), so you'll need to uninstall them manually. I think it is better to:

1. delete all installed gems from the current gemset (if there's no rvm then I think there's no much difference with `bundle update rails`)

   `rvm gemset empty your_gemset_name`
2. install all gems you need that aren't mentioned in your Gemfile (possibly rake, bundler, maybe some other ones). For example if you have all gems installed in the global gemset then all gems will be deleted including bundler so you'll have to reinstall it first:

   `gem install rake`

   `gem install bundler`
3. install gems with the help of bundler

   `bundle install`
4. run tests
5. manually check functionality if tests do not cover 100% of the code

In this way you'll get rid of unnecessary old versions of gems automatically and also during `bundle install` bundler will let you know if there are any mismatches in gems versions.

Comment: thanks for the help! If I have both rails 3.2.3 and 3.2.11 installed will the security flaw still be patched? What is the disadvantage of having 2 versions of rails installed?

Comment: Your application will be using only one version of rails in any case, so if you have 3.2.11 in Gemfile (and ran either command to apply it) then security flaw is patched. Disadvantage of having 2 versions is that you keep things that you don't need and with time.there will be a mess in your gemset.

Answer (score 0):

When i update rails i do it the same way like you just

```
gem 'rails', 'VERSION'
```

this is enough. To know about the gem dependencies i do this steps if iam not sure:

## 1

check the gem pages (in my case its mostly the git pages i follow)

## 2

run my test cases to see if errors occure related to the new rails version

## 3

test gems manualy, offen its the case that you have little gems for maybe 1-2 features on the page. Just klick through them.

In your case i would say its a little update so dont worry about so much just think about what each gem is doing and quick test! Its more common that gems cant handle old rails versions then new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm upgrading to rails 3.2.11 today too.  After changing the gem file and running `bundle update rails` I now run `gem list` and find that I have rails 3.2.9 and 3.2.11 installed.  I also found other gems that need cleaning up as well.  Here's a great SO post I found on cleaning up these older versions: [Uninstall old versions of Ruby gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902488/uninstall-old-ruby-gems-versions).